# Ошибка RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, threading

Вот код:

```
from threading import Timer
import discord as ds
bot = ds.Client(command_prefix='!', intents=ds.Intents.all())

async def f():
    user = await bot.fetch_user('id')

    await user.send('привет')
    Timer(5, f).start()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('reddy to work.')
    await f()

bot.run('token')
```

Мне нужно выполнять асинхронную функцию f() через каждое фиксированное количество времени, для этого использовал Time(), но выводится ошибка:
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'f' was never awaited self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Пытался добавлять и убирать await в некоторых местах, добавлять библиотеку asyncio, не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, вам нужно чтобы бот начал определенный цикл.
Для этого можно использовать:

```
    while True:
        try:
            #код
        except:
            break
```

Таким образом бот будет постоянно включать `#код` пока по какой-нибудь причине не получит ошибку.
Например:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('reddy to work.')
    user = await bot.fetch_user('id')
    while True:
        try:
            await user.send('привет')
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
        except:
            break
```